# lost with FPDI setSourceFile()

Tags: php, pdf, split, fpdi

I'm a bit lost with Fpdi, I was trying to do other things, but seeing that nothing worked I was just trying the most basic thing I could think of. I don't know why the setSourceFile () part does not work, but I couldn't find the problem...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5gEd.png)

Comment: [You should not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please paste it as a code block

Comment: Also what does "nothing worked" mean? What error message do you have?